# @ symbol in object key

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I don't know the proper place to post this question but I was reading the Marionette docs and saw the following code when describing

[Marionette.Behaviors](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.2/marionette.behavior.html):

```
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    ui: {
        "destroy": ".destroy-btn"
    },

    events: {
        "click @ui.destroy": "warnBeforeDestroy"
    }
```

I have never seen an `@` symbol in an object key before.  Does the `@` mean anything or is it just part of the string and does nothing special?

Comment: It's just part of the string that is the key for that object.  There's nothing special about it.

Comment: @Eclecticist Thanks!  I was thinking it was just part of the string but did not know symbols other than underscores were valid.  Thanks!

Comment: That's not JSON, that's just a JavaScript object literal. [JSON is a text data format](http://json.org) that is based on JavaScript.

Comment: From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects): "An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** The string starting with the `@` symbol in the property name of an events object in a Backbone.Marionette view is parsed by Marionette. Marionette will match the string after `@ui.` and replace it with the corresponding value in that view's `ui` hash. In your example, `"click @ui.destroy"` becomes `"click .destroy-btn"`.

---

### Marionette `ui`

Marionette was enhanced with a little syntactic sugar to help you better organize the DOM dependencies in your view. In other words, marionette views can make use of an `ui` hash in your view that holds references to DOM elements inside that view's `el`. In your example you set

```
ui: {
  "destroy": ".destroy-btn"
}
```

This assumes that your view template will have at least one element with class `.destroy-btn`. After your view is rendered, Marionette will call `view.bindUIElements`and each member of your `ui` hash will be populated with the jQuery object that represents the element(s) that match the selector passed in to the `ui` object.

Thus, in your view, `this.ui.destroy` will return the jQuery object for the selector `.destroy-btn` *inside* your view's `el`.

#### Marionette parses the `events` hash

The other thing Marionette will do for you, and **this is where your question comes in**, is parse your `events` hash. If it finds any `events` properties that include an `@ui.` prefix it will capture the string after the `.` and return the selector stored in your `ui` hash.

So, if you have

```
events: {
  "click @ui.destroy": "warnBeforeDestroy"
}
```

Marionette will hand Backbone an `events` hash that looks like:

```
events: {
  "click .destroy-btn": "warnBeforeDestroy"
}
```

### Further reference

See [Marionette events](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.2/marionette.view.html#viewevents)
and [bindUIElements](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.2/marionette.view.html#viewbinduielements)

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  My initial impression was that the `@` was part of the string, but it was unclear if it did something different in Marionette to me.  Thanks!

Comment: It's an excellent question. You did a service to our community for asking it. So, my pleasure, and thank you, too!

Answer (score 1):

Those are just normal object keys. Nothing special about them.

```
var events = {
    "click @ui.destroy": "warnBeforeDestroy"
};

events["click @ui.destroy"]; // 'warnBeforeDestroy'
```

It looks like those are probably special in the context of Marionette, but that is independent of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a format for describing objects as text data, so there are no JSON objects... only JSON strings, like `"[1,2,3]"` that is JSON representation for an array of three elements.

What you're showing is a Javascript object and they can use any string as key and the character `@` is really nothing special.

If you try to use something that is not a string as key it will work anyway by first converting it to a string... for example:

```
var obj1 = {};
obj1[12] = 99;
console.log(obj1["12"]);
```

Note that if you want to use a Javascript object as a dictionary for generic storage you can bump into problems with inherited attributes... for example:

```
var obj2 = {};
if (obj2["constructor"]) { console.log("What? not empty?"); }
```

you can however detect if a key is inherited or part of the specific object instance with `hasOwnProperty`.